# Empty buffer after successful recv

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, winsock, recv

I'm writing a server on Windows in C++ and I'm facing a strange behavior using `recv()`.

I wrote this function:

```
bool readN(SOCKET s, int size, char* buffer){
    fd_set readset;
    struct timeval tv;
    int left, res;
    FD_ZERO(&readset);
    FD_SET(s, &readset);
    left = size;
    std::cout << "-----called readN to read " << size << " byte" << std::endl;
    while (left > 0) {
        tv.tv_sec = MAXWAIT;
        tv.tv_usec = 0;
        res = select(0, &readset, NULL, NULL, &tv);
        if (res > 0) {
            res = recv(s, buffer, left, 0);
            if (res == 0) {//connection closed by client
                return false;
            }

            left -= res;
            std::cout << "\treceived " << res << " left " << left << std::endl;
            if (left != 0) {
                buffer += res;
            }

        }
        else if (res == 0) { //timer expired
            return false;
        }
        else { //socket error
            return false;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "\t" << buffer << std::endl;
    return true;
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer = std::make_unique<char[]>(size_);
if (readN(sck, size_, buffer.get())) {
    std::cout << "----read message----" << std::endl;
    std::cout <<"\t"<< buffer.get()<< std::endl;
}
```

The problem is that even if `recv()` returns a positive number, the buffer is still empty. What am I missing?

Comment: Define 'the buffer is still empty'. What's your evidence for that assertion? And you're ignoring the possibility that `recv()` has returned -1.

Comment: I suggest you debug the code. specifically break on the recv call and examine the buffer afterwards, really more reasonable than asking others to mentally debug it.

Comment: I debugged the program, the value returned by recv is positive but the buffer content is '\0', but still you're right, I'm not handling the -1 case.

Comment: What makes you think the other end didn't send you some `'\0'` bytes?  Try filling with (eg) `'\0x5A'`, before the call, and see if it changes.

Comment: @MartinBonner I just tried, the buffer is overwritten with \0 after recv()

Comment: In that case, you are being sent a number of `\0` bytes.  If that is not what you expect, you have a bug which needs to be fixed.

Comment: The fact that the buffer contains nulls is not evidence that it is empty. NB you have another problem. You should re-initialize `readfds` every time around the loop, before calling `select()`.

Comment: please add winsock tag.. you can sniff the traffic with wireshark and check the packet if its null filled (if this is network communication)

Comment: @MartinBonner I'm working with a client developed by someone else, I wrote a test client and it seems to work fine, probably there's a bug in the other guy client. I have another question though, as EJP mentioned I knew that on Linux i should re-initialize readfds and timeval but I didn't find anything on MSDN, is this necessary on windows too?

Comment: It is necessary everywhere. `select()` clears `readfd` bits that aren't ready, so of course you have to set them again.

Comment: If the client is sending padding bytes, you should either ignore them (or otherwise handle them correctly), or tell the author to stop sending them.  <shrug>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a few problems in your code.

1. you are not resetting the `readset` variable each time you call `select()`.  `select()` modifies the variable. For a single-socket case, this is not too bad, but you should get in the habit of resetting the variable each time.
2. you are not checking for errors returned by `recv()`. You assume any non-graceful-disconnect is success, but that is not always true.
3. at the end of `readN()` before returning `true`, you are outputting the `buffer` parameter to `std::cout`, however `buffer` will be pointing at the *END* of the data, not the *BEGINNING*, since it was advanced by the reading loop. This is likely where your confusion about an "empty buffer" is coming from.  `readN()` itself should not even be outputting the data at all, since you do that after `readN()` exits, otherwise you end up with redundant output messages.
4. if `readN()` returns true, you are passing the final `buffer` to `std::cout` using an `operator<<` that expects a null terminated `char` string, but your buffer is not guaranteed to be null-terminated.

Try something more like this instead:

```
bool readN(SOCKET s, int size, char* buffer){
    fd_set readset;
    struct timeval tv;
    int res;
    std::cout << "-----called readN to read " << size << " byte(s)" << std::endl;
    while (size > 0) {
        FD_ZERO(&readset);
        FD_SET(s, &readset);
        tv.tv_sec = MAXWAIT;
        tv.tv_usec = 0;

        res = select(0, &readset, NULL, NULL, &tv);
        if (res > 0) {
            res = recv(s, buffer, size, 0);
            if (res == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                res = WSAGetLastError();
                if (res == WSAEWOULDBLOCK) {
                    continue; //call select() again
                }
                return false; //socket error
            }

            if (res == 0) {
                return false;  //connection closed by client
            }

            buffer += res;
            size -= res;

            std::cout << "\treceived " << res << " byte(s), " << size << " left" << std::endl;
        }

        /*
        else if (res == 0) {
            return false; //timer expired
        }
        else {
            return false; //socket error
        }
        */

        else {
            return false; //timer expired or socket error
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer = std::make_unique<char[]>(size_);
if (readN(sck, size_, buffer.get())) {
    std::cout << "----read message----" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\t";
    std::cout.write(buffer.get(), size_);
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

With that said, I would suggest an alternative implementation of `readN()`, depending on whether you are using a blocking or non-blocking socket.

If blocking, use `setsockopt(SO_RCVTIMEO)` instead of `select()`.  If `recv()` fails with a timeout, `WSAGetLastError()` will report `WSAETIMEDOUT`:

```
sck = socket(...);

DWORD timeout = MAXWAIT * 1000;
setsockopt(sck, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char*)&timeout, sizeof(timeout));
```

```
bool readN(SOCKET s, int size, char* buffer){
    int res;
    std::cout << "-----called readN to read " << size << " byte(s)" << std::endl;
    while (size > 0) {
        res = recv(s, buffer, size, 0);
        if (res == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            /*
            res = WSAGetLastError();
            if (res == WSAETIMEDOUT) {
                return false; //timer expired
            }
            else {
                return false; //socket error
            }
            */
            return false; //timer expired or socket error
        }

        if (res == 0) {
            return false; //connection closed by client
        }

        buffer += res;
        size -= res;

        std::cout << "\treceived " << res << " byte(s), " << size << " left" << std::endl;
    }

    return true;
}
```

If non-blocking, don't call `select()` unless `recv()` asks you to call it:

```
bool readN(SOCKET s, int size, char* buffer){
    fd_set readset;
    struct timeval tv;
    int res;
    std::cout << "-----called readN to read " << size << " byte(s)" << std::endl;
    while (size > 0) {
        res = recv(s, buffer, size, 0);
        if (res == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            res = WSAGetLastError();
            if (res != WSAEWOULDBLOCK) {
                return false; //socket error
            }

            FD_ZERO(&readset);
            FD_SET(s, &readset);
            tv.tv_sec = MAXWAIT;
            tv.tv_usec = 0;

            res = select(0, &readset, NULL, NULL, &tv);
            if (res > 0) {
                continue; //call recv() again
            }

            /*
            else if (res == 0) {
                return false; //timer expired
            }
            else {
                return false; //socket error
            }
            */

            return false; //timer expired or socket error
        }

        if (res == 0) {
            return false; //connection closed by client
        }

        buffer += res;
        size -= res;

        std::cout << "\treceived " << res << " byte(s), " << size << " left" << std::endl;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the `readN()` there is

```
std::cout << "\t" << buffer << std::endl;
```

The problem is that the buffer points now to `buffer + size` in respect to the original value of `buffer`. The value has been modified by

```
buffer += res;
```

This should output the buffer,

```
std::cout << "\t" << (buffer - size) << std::endl;
```

After experimenting `readN()` with the following `main()`, it seems that `readN()` works if the socket is not invalid handle (text/binary data sent by ncat). If the socket is a invalid handle, the function returns quickly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string.h>

#ifdef _WIN64
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#else
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#endif

#include <errno.h>

#define MAXWAIT 5000

bool readN(SOCKET fd, int size, char *buffer)
{
    fd_set readset;
    struct timeval tv;
    int left, res;

    FD_ZERO(&readset);
    FD_SET(fd, &readset);

    left = size;
    std::cout << "-----called readN to read " << size << " byte" << std::endl;
    while (left > 0) {
        tv.tv_sec = MAXWAIT;
        tv.tv_usec = 0;
        res = select(fd + 1, &readset, NULL, NULL, &tv);

        if (res > 0) {
            res = recv(fd, buffer, left, 0);
            if (res == 0) { //connection closed by client
                return false;
            }

            left -= res;
            std::cout << "\treceived " << res << " left " << left << std::endl;
            buffer += res;
        } else if (res == 0) {  //timer expired
            std::cout << "\ttimer expired" << std::endl;
            return false;
        } else {        //socket error
            std::cout << "\tsocket error " << WSAGetLastError()  << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Print the buffer now\n" << (buffer - size) << std::endl;
    return true;
}

int main(void)
{
    int err;
    SOCKET cfd = 0;
    SOCKET afd = 0;

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    socklen_t clen;
    struct sockaddr_in caddr;

#ifdef _WIN64
    WORD ver = 0x202;
    WSADATA wsa_data;

    memset(&wsa_data, 0, sizeof(wsa_data));
    std::cout << "WSAStartup" << std::endl;
    err = WSAStartup(ver, &wsa_data);
    if (err < 0) goto error_exit;
#endif

    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    memset(&caddr, 0, sizeof(caddr));

    std::cout << "socket" << std::endl;
    afd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (afd < 0) goto error_exit;

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    addr.sin_port = htons(1234);

    std::cout << "bind" << std::endl;
    err = bind(afd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    if (err < 0) goto error_exit;

    std::cout << "listen" << std::endl;
    listen(afd, 5);

    clen = sizeof(caddr);
    std::cout << "accept" << std::endl;
    cfd = accept(afd, (struct sockaddr *) &caddr, &clen);
    if (cfd == INVALID_SOCKET) goto error_exit;

    {
        int size_ = 1024;
        std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer2 = std::make_unique<char[]>(size_);

        std::cout << "readN" << std::endl;
        if (readN(cfd, 1024, buffer2.get())) {
            std::cout << "----read message----" << std::endl;
            std::cout <<"\t"<< buffer2.get() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
error_exit:
    std::cout << "Error!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\tsocket error " << WSAGetLastError()  << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```